# ArrayList modifica los valores que fueron ingresados a la tabla anteriormente

Tags: java, arraylist

el proposito de el codigo a contiuacion es de guardarlos datos recibidos tras una consulta con ResultSet en una clase llamada Alimentos, para luego ser agregadas a un ArrayList.

**Codigo de la clase Alimentos**

```
public class Alimentos {

 private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private float calorias, proteinas, carbohidratos, vit_a, vit_b, vit_c, vit_k, fibra, calcio;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public float getCalorias() {
        return calorias;
    }

    public void setCalorias(float calorias) {
        this.calorias = calorias;
    }

    public float getProteinas() {
        return proteinas;
    }

    public void setProteinas(float proteinas) {
        this.proteinas = proteinas;
    }

    public float getCarbohidratos() {
        return carbohidratos;
    }

    public void setCarbohidratos(float carbohidratos) {
        this.carbohidratos = carbohidratos;
    }

    public float getVit_a() {
        return vit_a;
    }

    public void setVit_a(float vit_a) {
        this.vit_a = vit_a;
    }

    public float getVit_b() {
        return vit_b;
    }

    public void setVit_b(float vit_b) {
        this.vit_b = vit_b;
    }

    public float getVit_c() {
        return vit_c;
    }

    public void setVit_c(float vit_c) {
        this.vit_c = vit_c;
    }

    public float getVit_k() {
        return vit_k;
    }

    public void setVit_k(float vit_k) {
        this.vit_k = vit_k;
    }

    public float getFibra() {
        return fibra;
    }

    public void setFibra(float fibra) {
        this.fibra = fibra;
    }

    public float getCalcio() {
        return calcio;
    }

    public void setCalcio(float calcio) {
        this.calcio = calcio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alimentos{" + "id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", calorias=" + calorias + ", proteinas=" + proteinas + ", carbohidratos=" + carbohidratos + ", vit_a=" + vit_a + ", vit_b=" + vit_b + ", vit_c=" + vit_c + ", vit_k=" + vit_k + ", fibra=" + fibra + ", calcio=" + calcio + '}';
    }

}
```

**Metodo Cargar Alimentos, clase main (Alimento esta definido al comienzo de la clase)**

```
public void cargarAlimentos() {
    arregloAlimentos = new ArrayList<>();
    arregloAlimentos.clear();
    
    try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement(); //obj para realiza la conexion
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from alimentos");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Alimento.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            Alimento.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
            Alimento.setCalorias(rs.getFloat(3));
            Alimento.setProteinas(rs.getFloat(4));
            Alimento.setCarbohidratos(rs.getFloat(5));
            Alimento.setVit_a(rs.getFloat(6));
            Alimento.setVit_b(rs.getFloat(7));
            Alimento.setVit_c(rs.getFloat(8));
            Alimento.setVit_k(rs.getFloat(9));
            Alimento.setFibra(rs.getFloat(10));
            Alimento.setCalcio(rs.getFloat(11));
            arregloAlimentos.add(Alimento);
            System.out.println(Alimento.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR- No se pueden crear los botones");
    }
}
```

**Output en consola**

> Alimentos{id=1, nombre=Arroz, calorias=63.0, proteinas=1.0, carbohidratos=14.5, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=1.0, calcio=1.5}
> Alimentos{id=2, nombre=Pure, calorias=87.0, proteinas=2.0, carbohidratos=18.0, vit_a=7.0, vit_b=7.0, vit_c=8.0, vit_k=2.0,
> fibra=1.3, calcio=25.0}
> Alimentos{id=3, nombre=Fideos, calorias=137.0, proteinas=5.0, carbohidratos=25.0, vit_a=6.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=1.2, calcio=12.0}
> Alimentos{id=4, nombre=Pan, calorias=29.4, proteinas=1.2, carbohidratos=5.4, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=2.82, calcio=12.0}
> Alimentos{id=5, nombre=Empanada queso, calorias=273.0, proteinas=8.92, carbohidratos=20.76, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0,
> vit_k=0.0, fibra=0.7, calcio=0.0}
> Alimentos{id=6, nombre=Empanada pino, calorias=437.0, proteinas=13.0, carbohidratos=54.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0,
> vit_k=0.0, fibra=0.0, calcio=0.0}
> Alimentos{id=7, nombre=Lechuga, calorias=5.4, proteinas=0.3, carbohidratos=0.9, vit_a=111.0, vit_b=5.4, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=52.2,
> fibra=0.39, calcio=10.8}
> Alimentos{id=8, nombre=Palta, calorias=128.0, proteinas=1.6, carbohidratos=6.824, vit_a=5.6, vit_b=8.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=24.8,
> fibra=5.36, calcio=9.6}
> Alimentos{id=9, nombre=Tomate, calorias=22.0, proteinas=0.7, carbohidratos=4.0, vit_a=24.0, vit_b=17.8, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=1.0, calcio=10.0}
> Alimentos{id=10, nombre=Papa cocida, calorias=111.6, proteinas=2.4, carbohidratos=25.2, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=15.6, vit_c=0.0,
> vit_k=0.36, fibra=1.8, calcio=6.0}
> Alimentos{id=11, nombre=Aceituna verde, calorias=31.05, proteinas=0.2645, carbohidratos=1.15, vit_a=5.75, vit_b=0.0,
> vit_c=0.0, vit_k=3.68, fibra=0.92, calcio=27.83}
> Alimentos{id=12, nombre=Cebollla cruda, calorias=44.0, proteinas=1.0, carbohidratos=10.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=8.1, vit_c=0.0,
> vit_k=0.0, fibra=2.2, calcio=17.0}
> Alimentos{id=13, nombre=Manzana, calorias=65.0, proteinas=0.15, carbohidratos=15.5, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=2.0, calcio=6.0}
> Alimentos{id=14, nombre=Durazno, calorias=45.0, proteinas=1.0, carbohidratos=10.0, vit_a=24.0, vit_b=4.1, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=3.0,
> fibra=1.5, calcio=4.0}
> Alimentos{id=15, nombre=Pera, calorias=63.0, proteinas=0.4, carbohidratos=15.0, vit_a=1.0, vit_b=4.4, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=3.8,
> fibra=3.0, calcio=8.0}
> Alimentos{id=16, nombre=Kiwi, calorias=61.6, proteinas=0.8, carbohidratos=13.6, vit_a=4.0, vit_b=84.8, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=37.6,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=32.0}
> Alimentos{id=17, nombre=Carne blanca, calorias=160.0, proteinas=32.0, carbohidratos=0.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0,
> vit_k=0.0, fibra=0.0, calcio=6.0}
> Alimentos{id=18, nombre=Salchica, calorias=275.0, proteinas=15.8, carbohidratos=1.86, vit_a=19.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=10.04}
> Alimentos{id=19, nombre=Carne vacuno, calorias=788.0, proteinas=98.3, carbohidratos=0.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0,
> vit_k=0.0, fibra=0.0, calcio=68.5}
> Alimentos{id=20, nombre=Jamon, calorias=14.0, proteinas=2.26, carbohidratos=0.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=0.6}
> Alimentos{id=21, nombre=Leche, calorias=152.0, proteinas=8.14, carbohidratos=11.5, vit_a=80.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=2.39, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=306.0}
> Alimentos{id=22, nombre=Yogurt, calorias=92.0, proteinas=16.0, carbohidratos=5.68, vit_a=1.56, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=173.0}
> Alimentos{id=23, nombre=Queso, calorias=32.0, proteinas=2.25, carbohidratos=0.9, vit_a=17.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=129.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=67.2}
> Alimentos{id=24, nombre=Huevo, calorias=72.0, proteinas=6.0, carbohidratos=0.5, vit_a=90.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=49.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=24.0}
> Alimentos{id=25, nombre=Mantequilla, calorias=36.0, proteinas=0.0, carbohidratos=0.0, vit_a=34.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=1.0}
> Alimentos{id=26, nombre=lentejas, calorias=226.0, proteinas=18.0, carbohidratos=38.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=3.37,
> fibra=15.0, calcio=38.0}
> Alimentos{id=27, nombre=porotos, calorias=392.0, proteinas=14.0, carbohidratos=54.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=2.78, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=14.0, calcio=154.0}
> Alimentos{id=28, nombre=arveja, calorias=40.5, proteinas=2.7, carbohidratos=7.25, vit_a=19.0, vit_b=20.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=12.4,
> fibra=2.85, calcio=12.5}
> Alimentos{id=29, nombre=cafe, calorias=2.4, proteinas=0.2, carbohidratos=0.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=4.8}
> Alimentos{id=30, nombre=te, calorias=1.0, proteinas=0.0, carbohidratos=0.0, vit_a=0.0, vit_b=0.0, vit_c=0.0, vit_k=0.0,
> fibra=0.0, calcio=0.0}

**Imprimir datos del ArrayList**

```
 for (Alimentos a : arregloAlimentos) {
            System.out.println(a.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás modificando e insertando siempre la misma instancia de Alimento, necesitas crear un nuevo objeto en cada iteración:

```
try {
    Statement st = conn.createStatement(); //obj para realiza la conexion
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from alimentos");
    while (rs.next()) {
        Alimentos alimento = new Alimentos();
        alimento.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        ...
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR- No se pueden crear los botones");
}
```